# What is the probability that $2$ of $4$ captured elk have been tagged?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, problem-solving

> A forest contains 20 elk, of which 5 are captured, tagged, and then released. A certain time later, 4 of the 20 elk are captured. What is the probability
>   that 2 of these 4 have been tagged? What assumptions are you making?

Here's my attempt. First of all, I assume that if 3 or 4 of the members of the second capture are tagged then that group still counts because technically 2 of them are tagged. It is not explicitly stated in the question that no more than 2 are allowed to be tagged. I came up with the following result:

(C(5, 2)(16, 2) + C(5, 3)C(16, 1) + C(5, 4)C(16, 0))/C(20, 4) = 91/323.

My book says that the correct answer is 70/323. Since my answer was larger I figured that perhaps the author was asking for the probability of the group only containing two tagged members instead.

C(5, 2)(16, 2)/C(20, 4) = 80/323.

Close, but not close enough. Considering my inexperience i dare not question the author so I assume I've done something wrong. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out what I might've done wrong, could someone lend me a hand please?

Edit: The sixteens should be fifteens right? Let me try that and get back to you. Yep that was it. I helped myself, but I can't give myself a like. Unacceptable!

Comment: Sometimes the action of asking and putting the words together in your mind leads you to the answer yourself.  I'm glad to see that seems to be the case here.

Comment: If you think the answer is good enough technically you can answer your own question.